# Remove 0 from a pandas series containing lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a series that stores data as lists.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1],
                   'vl': [ [1, 0, 2], [0, 1, 5] ]
                 })
```

For lists containing `0`, I'd like to remove `0`s from the lists.

Expected output:

```
id   vl 

0    [1, 2]
1    [1, 5]
```

Comment: Okay, so what do you find difficult about the task? Did you try to break it down into logical steps? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for useful tools in Pandas, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pandas+modify+lists)? After trying these things, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Explode your column then filter your values:

```
df['vl'] = df['vl'].explode().loc[lambda x: x != 0].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df)

# Output
   id      vl
0   0  [1, 2]
1   1  [1, 5]
```

Alternative:

```
df['vl'] = df['vl'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i != 0])
print(df)

# Output
   id      vl
0   0  [1, 2]
1   1  [1, 5]
```

Comment: @kms. Does it solve your problem?